# Efficiently slicing and applying function between different rank arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Suppose we have an array X with shape (N, K), and an array Y with shape (N, P, K).

The goal is to efficiently compute some function f(x_i, y_i) for each i=1,...,N along axis 0. Note that x_i has shape (1, K) and y_i has shape (P, K).

The naive implementation I have is just a for loop over the first axis. It seems like there should be some way to do it in a more vectorized manner or use broadcasting rules to compute f on the full arrays X, Y in one step - rather than doing it for each i one-by-one. Any suggestions on a more efficient way of implementing this logic?

```
import numpy as np

N = 10
P = 7
K = 5

# Shape (N, K) array
X = [np.arange(0,K) for i in range(N)]
X = np.stack(X)

# Shape (N, P, K) array
Y = [(-1)**k for k in range(N*P*K)]
Y = np.array(Y).reshape(N,P,K)

# Some function f: 
# For simplicity, just adds x+y with shape broadcasting between a (1,K) array and (*, K) array
def f(x_i, y_batch):
    l = x_i + y_batch
    return l

# Goal: Efficiently compute some function f of the ith element (axis 0) of X and Y for each i=1,...,N, 

# Example: Naive Implementation
results = []
for i in range(N):
    x = X[i,:]
    y = Y[i,:,:]
    results.append( f(x,y) )
```

Comment: An idea is to copy each element of X, P times, so that it becomes a (N, P, K) array as well. Then we can just compute f(X,Y) directly - but this may be memory inefficient due to the unnecessary copies.

Comment: `X[:,None,:] + Y` should work.  By the rules of broadcasting a (N,1,K) array works with a (N,P,K) array.

Comment: `X` is of shape `(N, K-1)`. You might want `X = [np.arange(1,K+1) for i in range(N)]`. Then broadcasting is the way to go as @hpaulj explained.